# File System Private download method not Writeable -Drupal

Tags: filesystems, file-permissions, drupal

Giving File System error that it is not writeable or folder does not exist on Production Env

1. Drupal version  - **9.5.9**
2. Server we are using **Amazon Linux2**

   I have added line in setting.php $settings['file_private_path'] = $app_root . '/' . $site_path .'/files/private';

   Can somebody help me what exactly will be the permission and path to be set